# Issue with SQL in python with SELECT

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to use python to select items from an SQL database. Here is my code as I have it (the database works fine

```
for i in range(100):
    name1 = (crsr.execute("SELECT a FROM elections WHERE id = ?", (i,)))
    a = crsr.fetchall()
    print(a[0])
    name2 = (crsr.execute("SELECT b FROM elections WHERE id = ?", (i,)))
    b = crsr.fetchall()
    print(b[0])
    name3 = (crsr.execute("SELECT c FROM elections WHERE id = ?", (i,)))
    c = crsr.fetchall()
    print(c[0])
```

When I print just a, b, or c, it prints out an array with the items from the database. However, I need to access just the element (they are strings) at that point in the database, but when I try to access a[0] or b[0] or c[0], I get an 'index out of range' error.

Edit: when I print just a by itself, the following is printed:
[(string,)]

Comment: it would help if you showed us the output of your print statements

Comment: I would suspect that not every id has a resulting row from the database, and if it does not, the list is empty. Which crashes when you try to get the first element.

Comment: What sql library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Joachim's comment is correct. If `i` does not exist in the table, the cursor will still execute and store in the `cursor` object, including storing nothing if not found. At the first occurrence of this expression, `fetchall()` will return an empty list, which will not have a `0` index as you are trying to print with `print(a[0])`.

Try editing with this, and see if values return, please also confirm datatype of the `id` column of the SQL table.

```
name1 = (crsr.execute("SELECT a FROM elections WHERE id = ?", (i,)))
if name1 = None:
    print('No result')
else:
    a = crsr.fetchall()
    print(a[0])
```